# Background Color change on a gridview when comparing to fields to one another

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView, but I have to compare two fields to one another
but when the one field is greater than the other the field has to change to a certain color, how can I write this method in C#:

[image]

Comment: could you provide your current code?

Comment: please edit your answer and put the code there

Comment: Tell us at least what two fields you are referring to! Just a screen capture does not say that much.

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView`!! This is wrong and confusing and and bound to get wrong answers wasting everybody's time.. Always call things by their __right__ name!

Comment: Use the CellPainting event to set the colors!

Comment: This is Too Broad and we need more context. There are a handful of events you could use but without more information on what you've tried and a specific problem with those attempts, this just sounds like a homework question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick example:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView dgv = dataGridView1;
    if (e.ColumnIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex < 0) return;
    if (dgv[0, e.RowIndex].Value == null ||dgv[1, e.RowIndex].Value == null) return;
    // assuming integers, adapt to real types and real column indices!
    dgv[1, e.RowIndex].Style.BackColor = 
                            (int)dgv[0, e.RowIndex].Value < (int)dgv[1, e.RowIndex].Value ?
                                        Color.LightSalmon : dgv.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor;
}
```