# C# DataGridView BackColor Not Overwritten

Tags: c#, datagridview, backcolor

I have `DataGridView` on my form application. After retrieving data from a table in the database and displaying them in `DataGridView`, I apply a **green** color to some cell's *BackColor* of the rows if a certain condition is met. 
After those cells are colored **green**, the program makes them go through another condition, which colors the whole row's *BackColor* **red** if they fail to satisfy the condition.

However, it seems like pre-colored cells cannot be overwritten with a new color. 
Even if I apply the following code to color the whole row **red**, it only works for the cells that have not been pre-colored.

```
for(int i=0; i<myDataGridview.Rows.Count; i++){  
    if(/*a certain condition FAILS*/){
        myDataGridView.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Right now, I am coloring those pre-colored cells **red** one by one, but this takes a lot of time and code like:

```
for(int i=0; i<myDataGridview.Rows.Count; i++){  
    if(/*a certain condition FAILS*/){
        //Trying to color the whole row RED, but not working
        myDataGridView.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        //Manually color the cells, which are pre-colored to green, RED
        myDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[6].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
        myDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[7].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
        ....
        myDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[13].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
        myDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[16].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

I am wondering if there is a better way to override the backColor. Can someone please help?

Here is an example (imitation) DataGridView.

[image: Green Cells not overridden by Red Row]

Those who failed the first condition automatically get their whole row red, and that works. However, if they pass the first condition and get their "Passed1" cell colored green, and then fail the second condition, as you can see, those cells stay green. I want to color the whole row red, even overwriting the pre-colored-to-green cell to red.

Comment: a) explain 'precolored'! b) see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46337343/background-color-change-on-a-gridview-when-comparing-to-fields-to-one-another/46340828#46340828) for an example of coloring cells in the `CellPainting` event. If you code for the full set of conditions it should suffice.

Comment: If a new BackColor has been applied to a cell (meaning pre-colored), that cell's BackColor cannot be changed to another color, even if I try to color the whole row including that cell with myDataGridView.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor

Comment: That would be the difference between a default and an overridden value. Use the cell.BackColor to override a default value or a previous change! Also: Try to centralize all coloring etc in the CellPainting..

Comment: In the image I attached in my post, rows with ID:2, 4 and 5 cannot be fully colored to Red, and their "Passed1"  cells stay green.

Comment: Well if you just change the cell color to green, just that cell is changed, not the whole row.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: @Plutonix I know that. I am just wondering why applying color change to the whole row does not affect that cell that has already backColor. I guess my poor English is not making sense...

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  We dont have much context for when you are doing what....which is important in event driven programming.  I would not loop on all the rows to begin with because it is not efficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cell background colors have an order of precedence when the cell is drawn. Starting at the top, it will cascade down the list until the color is set*:

1. `Cell.Style.BackColor`
2. `Row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor`
3. `DataGridView.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor`
4. `DataGridView.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor`
5. `Column.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor`
6. `DataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor`

<sub>* This list is not extensive and may not include every possible BackColor accessible property.</sub>

---

It is likely you are doing something akin to setting `Cell.Style.BackColor` for cells in the `Passed1` column, then the code logic you posted. Which gives results like you're seeing because `Green` has a higher precedence than `Red` where it's set:

[image: Green Cells not overridden by Red Row]

Assuming your conditions for the two `Passed` columns is binary (`Yes` or `No`), you can fix this by "lowering" the precedence of `Green` background by setting the `Column.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor`:

```
private void DataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    this.dataGridView1.Columns["Passed1"].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
    this.dataGridView1.Columns["Passed2"].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells["Passed1"].Value.ToString() == "No" || row.Cells["Passed2"].Value.ToString() == "No")
        {
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

Which results in:

[image: Green Cells overridden by Red Rows]

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the answer I was wanting. I had no clue that there was an order of precedence. That was the one causing my problem. I am glad you understood my question correctly.

Comment: In all fairness, I've never found a list of this *order* anywhere - not even in my searches of MSDN documentation.  I only know from trial and error.

Comment: I just wanted to thank you again. I am working on my new project and I had a very similar issue to this, and I came back to this _order of precedence_, and it fixed the issue immediately. Thank you thank you thank you.

Comment: That's awesome!  Glad to help. :)

Comment: @OhBeWise had a similar issue, i personally think it's odd the the latest doesn't overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the datagridview control in that you cannot change the color of any of the cells until AFTER the form has been shown by using DefaultCellStyle property. Thus methods that run, or events that fire before Shown() is called will not change the color. That's the problem probably.May you have to create a painting method and call it before Shown().