# dataGridView only showing selected row? Not all rows when it loads (C# wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview

I'm unsure what happened. But it is affecting all my tables. Just a few hours ago when a page/form loads my datagrid view would show all the data in the table at once. Now everything is blank/white unless I click my mouse on the cell and it highlights the whole row but still does not show the other rows unless I click on the cells.

[First cell selected, shows the whole row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfyBi.png)

[Second row shows but first row is now hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0AMe.png)

How do I fix this? Everything was fine a few hours ago. I didn't even make any changes to my datagridview and now their all affected.

```
  private void Add_Products_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  {

        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        con.Open();
        displayproduct_info();
        fill_combobox();
    }





    public void displayproduct_info() {
        //comboBox1.Items.Clear();
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from Product_listing";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order to help fix any issues, we are going to need to actually see the code...

Comment: Added. Sorry about that.

Comment: Check to see if your text coloring has been changed to white.  [In this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46352904/3773066) I mention several possible locations - just replace `BackColor` with `ForeColor`.

Comment: After some testing. It seems the mdi main parent is the one causing the issues to all my gridviews across all my child forms. I could not find which of the settings in properties was causing this issue.  I made a new mdi parent with the same code but hardly touched properties and all the tables load with everything showing.